# Summarizing the data in a data table

Tags: r, dataframe, formatting, data-manipulation

Hi I have the following input.

```
+------+----+----+
| CODE | R1 | R2 |
+------+----+----+
| A    |  0 |  1 |
| B    |  1 |  1 |
| C    |  0 |  0 |
+------+----+----+
```

I need the output like below.

```
+------+------+-------+
| CODE | CODE | VALUE |
+------+------+-------+
| A    | R1   |     0 |
| A    | R2   |     1 |
| B    | R1   |     1 |
| B    | R2   |     1 |
| C    | R1   |     0 |
| C    | R2   |     0 |
+------+------+-------+
```

Please note that the regions such as `R1` and `R2`, there are many regions in the actual data like `R3`,`R4`,`R5` and so on. For simplicity, I put only `R1` and `R2`.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Don't know why the it is not coming in the table format

Comment: Hi @avinash0513, please check the formatting once my edit is accepted & you can follow that if you come back with more questions :)

Comment: this will help you in future questions: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), to modify your question, with a smaller sample taken from your data (check `?dput()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `data.table`, we can use `melt`

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df1), id.var = 'CODE')
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty classic scenario to transform data from **wide to long format**. And straight forward to use `pivot-longer` from [tidyr](/questions/tagged/tidyr):

```
df <- read.table(stringsAsFactors = F, header = T, text = "
           CODE R1  R2
           A    0   1
           B    1   1
           C    0   0");

dfTarget <- read.table(stringsAsFactors = F, header = T, text = "
 CODE  CODE  VALUE 
 A     R1        0 
 A     R2        1 
 B     R1        1 
 B     R2        1 
 C     R1        0 
 C     R2        0");
```

Now, the code that you want:

```
df %>% pivot_longer(cols = c("R1","R2"), values_to = "VALUE")
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  CODE  name  VALUE
  <chr> <chr> <int>
1 A     R1        0
2 A     R2        1
3 B     R1        1
4 B     R2        1
5 C     R1        0
6 C     R2        0

colnames(df)[1:2] <- c("CODE1", "CODE2"); #to change the column names, dataframe 
#with duplicate column names is not a good idea.
```

You can find a comprehensive overview of [pivoting here @ https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html)